# Deriving a system of PDE's given a system of global conservation laws

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stokes-theorem

This is a homework question. I just cannot wrap my head around on how to solve these kinds of questions. The question is as follows

> Consider the following system of global conservation laws
>
> $$ -\int_C \vec{H} \cdot d\vec{r} + \epsilon_0 \frac{d}{dt}
>  \iint_{\Sigma} \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{S} = -\iint_{\Sigma} \vec{J}
>  \cdot d\vec{S} $$
>
> where $C$ is the boundary of the curve of the surface $\Sigma$ and all conditions of the Divergence and Stoke's Theorem are satisfied.
>   Assuming that these global conservation laws hold for any $\Sigma$ ,
>   derive the corresponding system of partial differential equations.

So the question states that Stoke's Theorem can be used. This means that

$$\int_C \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} = \iint_{\Sigma} \nabla \cdot \vec{F} dS $$

Then the system of global conservation laws becomes

$$ - \iint_{\Sigma} \nabla \cdot \vec{H} dS + \epsilon_0 \frac{d}{dt} \iint_{\Sigma} \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{S} = - \iint_{\Sigma} \vec{J} \cdot d\vec{S} $$

but I do not know how to rewrite the second and the third term in order to get rid of the inner product between $d\vec{S}$ and the other term. I know that eventually, because of the mean-value theorem, the double integrals and $dS$ term of each part of the equation can be divided out.

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something or am I interpreting Stoke's theorem incorrectly?

Comment: Are you sure that it shouldn't be $\int_{C} \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}= \int_\Sigma (\nabla \times \vec{F})\cdot d\vec{S}$?

Comment: As a bonus for this I'm pretty sure that gives the Maxwell-Ampere law

Comment: (By the way, the name of the guy is Stokes, not Stoke.)

Comment: @KitterCatter Checking wikipedia right now and you're right. I watched a bunch of videos regarding conservation laws and got things mixed up. However, then this equality does not bring us much further to converting it into a PDE... Do you have any idea how to approach this problem?

Comment: I don't think the inner product matter because you can rewrite everything as $ \iint_\Sigma [-(\nabla \times \vec{H})+ \epsilon_0 \frac{d\vec{E}}{dt} + \vec{J}] \cdot d\vec{S}=0$ so what is inside has to be equal to zero